# isSupported() always returns false when trying to call a native function in codename one

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to call the sayHi() function below that is implemented in the NativeTestImpl.java

These are my files :

NativeTest.java

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import com.codename1.system.NativeInterface;

public interface NativeTest extends NativeInterface {
    public String sayHi();  
}
```

NativeTestImpl.java

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;
public class NativeTestImpl implements com.mycompany.myapp.NativeTest {
    public String sayHi() {
        return "HI";
    }

    public boolean isSupported() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

MyApplication.java's start() method :

```
 public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        String s=null;
        try
        {
            NativeTest obj = (NativeTest)NativeLookup.create(NativeTest.class);
            if(obj != null && obj.isSupported())
            {
                s=obj.sayHi();
            }
            else
            {
                 System.out.println("Native interface is not supported on this platform");
            }
        }
        catch(Throwable t) {
            Dialog.show("Error", "Exception during native access: " + t, "OK", null);
        }

        final Form f = new Form("Testing");
        f.setScrollable(false);
        TextField text=new TextField(s);
        f.addComponent(text);
        f.show();
    }
```

The problem is that obj.isSupported() is returning false when I run it on the emulator with a nexus skin. I ran it in debug mode and saw that obj is not null. Only the obj.isSupported() function call is returning false so it is going into the else part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you haven't implemented the simulator native interface under the native/javase dir

Comment: Ok this was the problem. Thanks. I ran it on my android device and it was working so I figured it would be some problem with the simulator native code.